# how to get serialized data from $post and loop through it?

Tags: jquery, arrays, post, jquery-cloneya

I have a form that uses Cloneya, a jquery plugin that enables the easy management select and inputbox cloning.

my html form is like:

```
  <div class="spacer-b10 colm colm2">
    <label class="prepend-icon"><input type="text" name="acc_code[1]" id="acc_code"
    class="gui-input" placeholder="Code" /> </label>
  </div>

  <div class="spacer-b10 colm colm2">
    <label class="field select"><select id="acc_name" name="acc_name[1]" style=
    "font-size:12x">
      <option value="">
        Account
      </option>

      <option value="Administrator">
        Administrator
      </option>

      <option value="Read Only">
        Read Only
      </option>
    </select> </label>
  </div>
```

The cloneya plugin automatically creates element names.

Then I have the following ajax script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#account2').submit(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault(); // Prevent Default Submission

                $.ajax({
                        url: 'submit.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: $(this).serialize() // serialize the form data
                    })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $('#form-content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            $('#form-content').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                        });
                    })
                    .fail(function() {
                        alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
                    });
            });
```

In my file check.php I want to make sure to get all $_post in form whether array or not and if these are arrays, to make sure to loop through all cloned elements (for DB inserting).

What would be the best method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `serializeArray()` and send the form as `JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)`:

```js
var paramsToSend = {};
paramsToSend['form'] = $('#account2').serializeArray();

$.ajax({
    url: 'submit.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      params: JSON.stringify(paramsToSend)
    },
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    $('#form-content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
      $('#form-content').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
    });
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
  });
});
```

In your server-side, **submit.php**, you can:

```
$parameters = json_decode($_POST['params']);
```

To convert them to array and have that array in `$_POST`, you can:

```
$_POST = (array) $parameters;
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this asap